# How can I control the JSON serialization of an OpenApiExample object

Tags: azure-functions, openapi-generator, json-serialization

We have an endpoint that returns a list of events. Each event can have a different type, but all events inherit the generic Event type.  In order to correctly deserialize the events in our consumers we use serialize with these settings:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }
```

This includes the member `"$type": "Solution.Project.Events.SpecificEvent, Solution.Project"` in our actual payloads, so consumers can distinguish between the different events.

We're trying to implement a custom response example in our azure function, using the `OpenApiResponseWithBody` decorator and a call that inherits `OpenApiExample<List<T>>` as described here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-core.md#openapirequestbodyattribute, but in the Swagger UI the events are serialized without the TypeNameHandling settings.

Is there a way to add these settings?